# When running rails s I am getting this lazy symbol error. I am running on macOS Big Sur version 11.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, macos-big-sur

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _*ZN2v82V821AddGCPrologueCallbackEPFvNS_6GCTypeENS_15GCCallbackFlagsEES1*
Referenced from: /Users/tsaba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _*ZN2v82V821AddGCPrologueCallbackEPFvNS_6GCTypeENS_15GCCallbackFlagsEES1*
Referenced from: /Users/tsaba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

zsh: abort      rails s

Comment: Can you follow up on this issue?